# searchFromRecord(String, String) in Java doesn't work properly

Tags: java, full-text-search

I am trying to find if a specific word exists in a file. My code is:

```
private boolean searchFromRecord(String recordName, String word) throws IOException   {

File file = new File(recordName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

for (int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    String compare = scanner.nextLine();
    IO.outputln("word#" + i + ":" + compare);
    return compare.contains(word);
}
```

However when I check it only the first line of the file is printed and checked. I tried using an `if` statement instead of `return compare.contains(word)` such as:

```
if (compare.contains(word))
    return true
else 
    return false
```

However it does not work. Only the first line is printed and checked. Any hints?

Comment: Do you need to identify all the places where the word occurs, or can you return early if you see the word once? I ask because you're producing output in your loop; I don't know if that's just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`return` always stops the execution of your function, regardless of whether you're returning true or false.

---

Use that if-statement, except **don't** `return false` with an else.

Instead, `return false` after the loop has executed

```
for(int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++){

   ...

    if (compare.contains(word)
        return true
}
return false
```

Comment: Thank for your help. although it worked in BlueJ, this solution failed in Edx grader stating that I was missing return statement. probably I should have used scaner.close() return false. The solution was with the use of a while loop. ANYWAY THANKS TO EVERYBODY FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 2):

You are returning from within the `for` loop, preventing it from looping. You need to set a variable in the loop and only return after the loop is done:

```
boolean isWordPresent = false;

for (int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    String compare = scanner.nextLine();
    IO.outputln("word#" + i + ":" + compare);
    isWordPresent |= compare.contains(word);
}

return isWordPresent;
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it is inneficient because you will loop through the entire file regardless of whether or not the word has been found. If you used a condition such as `if(compare.contains(word)) return true` you can return as soon as the word is found without searching further.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the output was important; returning early changes that, but it might be what the OP wants.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of it that way. Guess it just depends on what's more important, the output, or whether or not the word exists. If it's just about whether or not the word exists, I don't see why OP needs output anyways. Your method might be best.

Comment: The output may very well have only been there for debugging purposes. I suspect it was, and added a comment to the question asking that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the return statement inside your for loop, and so you will automatically return after one iteration. Try changing to this:

```
for(int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++){
    String compare = scanner.nextLine();
    IO.outputln("word#" + i + ":" + compare);
    if(compare.contains(word))
        return true; // Will return true if word is found in this line, if not, just continue onto next line.
}
return false; // If you hit the end of the loop and never found the word, then you can return false, assuming the word was not inside the file.
```

Comment: Taht's what I submitted at the end, however I was not graded because I should have imported scanner.close(); before the return false statement. Anyway, thanks for your help. I hope I have learned from my mistakes....

Comment: Yikes, I'm a third year Computer Engineering student and I've never been marked down for that. Nor was I ever taught to do so. Glad I could help though!

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
return compare.contains(word);
```

Causes your method to **instantly return** to the caller, stopping it from iterating through the whole of your for loop.

You need to move the return to outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

instead of return use 
`System.out.println(""+compare.contains(word));`

As when you return the loop is not continued any more so dont use that